# My designer demolished and not found

Tags: c#, designer

Today I opened my project and saw this error, I can't open my designer for this error. I clicked on (ignore and continue) but it shows an empty form. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: You could at least copy-paste that error call stack which is clearly available, as seen on the screenshot.

Comment: Start a build and look for errors in the .designer.cs file. This file seems to be corrupted or has incorrect curly brackets. Look in your designer code for unclosed brackets etc. and close them correctly.

Comment: Unless you can roll back to a previous version you will have to try to fix the formDesigenr.cs file, which is most  likely messed up. Somtimes it helps to copy pieces of it into a new project. Obviously you should save the current state before you try the repair or the reconstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it seems the `Form1.Designer.resx` is broken.

The file has an XML file layout so it would be quite easy to spot missing closed tags, etc. The file can store images used too so it can get quite large.

If you really can't rescue it, you could delete it. Often most information is already in the `Form1.Designer.cs` file.